# ORA-00917: missing comma on DATE column

Tags: sql, oracle

I had come across many queries similar to the mentioned title. But my situation is quite different. I am trying to run the `INSERT` command for a table which has `SELECT` query to populate the column values. Below is the query I'm trying to execute.

```
INSERT INTO ELEC_ORDER_HT (OMS_SEQ.NEXTVAL, CUST_ID, ORDER_DATE, SHIP_METHOD,
  REC_CREN_TM, REC_HIST_CREN_TM AS '23-NOV-17 01.56.01.103000 AM', ORDER_ID) 
SELECT ELEC_ORDER.CUST_ID AS CUST_ID, ELEC_ORDER.ORDER_DATE AS ORDER_DATE,
  ELEC_ORDER.SHIP_METHOD AS SHIP_METHOD, ELEC_ORDER.REC_CREN_TM AS REC_CREN_TM,
  ELEC_ORDER.ORDER_ID AS ORDER_ID
FROM ELEC_ORDER
WHERE ELEC_ORDER.CUST_ID = 'CSTMR10001'
AND ELEC_ORDER.ORDER_ID = 'ELORD10001';
```

Number of column in `ELEC_ORDER_HT` and `ELEC_ORDER` tables are different. I got the following error when I executed the above query.

```
  REC_CREN_TM, REC_HIST_CREN_TM AS '23-NOV-17 01.56.01.103000 AM', ORDER_ID)
                                *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00917: missing comma
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO ELEC_ORDER_HT (
  OMS_SEQ.NEXTVAL, -- This does not appear to be a column name
  CUST_ID,
  ORDER_DATE,
  SHIP_METHOD,
  REC_CREN_TM,
  REC_HIST_CREN_TM AS '23-NOV-17 01.56.01.103000 AM', -- you cannot use aliases here
  ORDER_ID
)
SELECT ELEC_ORDER.CUST_ID AS CUST_ID,
       ELEC_ORDER.ORDER_DATE AS ORDER_DATE,
       ELEC_ORDER.SHIP_METHOD AS SHIP_METHOD,
       ELEC_ORDER.REC_CREN_TM AS REC_CREN_TM,
       ELEC_ORDER.ORDER_ID AS ORDER_ID         -- only 5 columns but 7 in the previous part
FROM   ELEC_ORDER
WHERE  ELEC_ORDER.CUST_ID = 'CSTMR10001'
AND    ELEC_ORDER.ORDER_ID = 'ELORD10001';
```

Is not valid. The syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO table_name ( column_name, column_name )
SELECT value, value FROM other_table
```

You appear to be trying to replace column names with constants/sequence values and then omitting those values from the `SELECT` statement.

You want something like:

```
INSERT INTO ELEC_ORDER_HT (
  OMS,                      -- or whatever the correct column name is
  CUST_ID,
  ORDER_DATE,
  SHIP_METHOD,
  REC_CREN_TM,
  REC_HIST_CREN_TM,
  ORDER_ID
)
SELECT OMS_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
       CUST_ID,
       ORDER_DATE,
       SHIP_METHOD,
       REC_CREN_TM,
       TIMESTAMP '2017-11-23 01.56.01.103000', -- or SYSTIMESTAMP if you want current time
       ORDER_ID
FROM   ELEC_ORDER
WHERE  CUST_ID = 'CSTMR10001'
AND    ORDER_ID = 'ELORD10001';
```

Comment: Thanks very much. The above approach worked well. Thanks a lot for your immediate support.